# Launch AMIs from AWS Marketplace via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, openvpn, aws-marketplace

does anyone know if it is possible to launch **Marketplace AMIs** (in this case an OpenVPN Server),
**via Cloudformation** and if so how? I didn't find anything helpful in the AWS Docs / OpenVPN Docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just do a quick test with this template and CloudFormation runs without error. Note that, my region is Singapore, I think you need to replace the `ImageId` of your region.

To get the ImageId, you need to launch an EC2 instance with the image in the console. From there you can copy the ImageId.

Those might be helpful:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
        ImageId: ami-0a8fdce33ca9cbe51 #ap-southeast-1
        KeyName: testkey
        InstanceType: t2.small
        SubnetId: subnet-035***095
        SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-03f***356
        BlockDeviceMappings:
        -
          DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 8
```

Comment: So which image is that? I'm not able to finde the ImageIds of Marketplace AMIs..

Comment: You are right, I created an EC2 to get the ImageId then add it in the template.